# Question about a step in Stein's proof that the Fourier transform of $-2\pi ixf(x)$ is $\frac{d}{d\xi} \hat{f}(\xi)$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I am looking at the proof that if $f$ is a Scwhartz function, i.e., $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ then the Fourier transform of $-2\pi ixf(x)$ is $\frac{d}{d\xi} \hat{f}(\xi)$.

For the proof, let $\epsilon >0$ and consider 
$$\frac{\hat{f}(\xi +h)-\hat{f}(\xi)}{h}-(\widehat{-2\pi ixf})(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\Big[\frac{e^{-2\pi ixh}-1}{h}+2\pi ix\Big] dx.$$

I have a question about the step in the attached proof below. In the proof, we make $$\int_{|x|\ge N}\Big|f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\Big[\frac{e^{-2\pi ixh}-1}{h}+2\pi ix\Big]\Big|dx \le C\epsilon.$$ To show this I think the authors intend to split this into two integrals, so $\int_{|x|\ge N}\Big|f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi} 2\pi ix\Big|dx\le 2\pi \epsilon$ and $\int_{|x|\ge N}\Big|f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\frac{e^{-2\pi ixh}-1}{h}\Big|dx\le C'\epsilon.$ However, I don't know how to bound the second integral using $\int_{|x|\ge N} |f(x)|dx \le \epsilon$, since here we have $\Big|\frac{e^{-2\pi ixh}-1}{h}\Big|\le \frac{2}{|h|}$ and $|h|$ is supposed to be small, hence this part goes unbounded. So how can we deal with this fraction when $|x|\ge N$ to bound the integral as in the proof below? I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: come on we answered that on your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938990/proof-that-the-fourier-transform-is-differentiable-for-schwartz-space-functions so make more efforts please, read different courses, do some research on the forum

Comment: @user1952009 Oh I just read your comment below about the inequality. But still I think the answer below helps as it shows how to get it. Anyways thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Can you write a proof of $f \in C^2 \implies $ what I wrote ? (hint : intermediate value theorem)

Comment: @user1952009 you mean $f(y)=e^{-2\pi iy}$ is in $C^2$? In this case, isn't it obvious? As we know the second derivative is exponential as well. Otherwise, can you explain what you're exactly asking for?

Comment: a proof that if $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ then there exists $c$ such that $|f(y) - f(0)-y f'(0)| < c y^2$ for $|y| < 1$

Comment: @user1952009 I've been thinking about this, but I can only resort to the proof of Taylor's formula. I can't think of an easy way to get this using the intermediate value theorem. Can you give me a hint? Also, we have a complex valued function given here. So does it mean that this result applies as long as the domain is real?

Comment: It is the proof of Taylor's theorem. By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there is a $c(y) \in (0,y)$ such that $ f'(c(y)) =\frac{f(y)-f(0)}{y}$. And there is a $d(y) \in (0,c(y))$ such that $\frac{f'(c(y))-f'(0)}{c(y)} = f''(d(y))$, hence $f(y) = f(0)+y f'(c(y)) = f(y)+f(0) + y f'(0)+ y c(y) f''(d(y))$ and by definition $|y(c(y)) f''(d(y))| \le | y^2| \sup_{ t \in [-1,1]}   |f''(t)|$  for $|y| < 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you this is wonderful. So in the case of complex valued functions, we can just split it into the real and imaginary parts and using the triangle inequality, we get the same bound $O(y^2)$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually use that
$$
|e^{-2πixh}-1+2πixh|\le C\,x^2h^2
$$
and that 
$$
\int_{-∞}^∞|f(x)|\,|x|^2\,dx
$$
is finite for the rapidly falling Schwartz test functions.

---

\begin{align}
|e^{-2iu}-1+2iu|&=|-2i\sin(u)+2iue^{iu}|
\\
&\le2\,|\sin(u)-u\cos(u)|+2|u\sin(u)|
\\
&\le|\sin(\theta u)u^2|+2|u|\min(1,|u|)\le 3u^2
\end{align}
as per Taylor $$0=\sin(0)=\sin(u-u)=\sin(u)-\cos(u)u-\frac12\sin(θu)u^2$$ with $θ\in(0,1)$.

One could argue that the first term is locally of third order, but that does not help the proof.

Comment: Can you tell me where we can get the first bound?

Comment: @takecare $f(y) = e^{-2i \pi y}$ is $C^2$ at $y = 0$ so  as $y \to 0$ : $f(y) = f(0) + yf'(0) + \mathcal{O}(y^2)$ which means precisely that there exists a $C$ such that $|f(y) - f(0) - y f'(0)| < C y^2$ for $|y|$ small enough, say for $|y| < 1$. Since $e^{-2i \pi y}$ is  $1$ periodic, it means that $|f(y) - f(0) - y f'(0)| < C y^2$ is true for every $y  \in \mathbb{R}$.   Finish with $y = xh$